# Text Adventure Game - How to Tell One Item Type from Another and How to Structure the Item Classes/Subclasses?

Tags: c++, game-development, adventure

I'm a beginner programmer (who has a bunch of design-related scripting experience for video games but very little programming experience - so just basic stuff like loops, flow control, etc. - although I do have a C++ fundamentals and C++ data structures and algorithm's course under my belt). I'm working on a text-adventure personal project (I actually already wrote it in Python ages ago before I learned how classes work - everything is a dictionary - so it's shameful). I'm "remaking" it in C++ with classes to get out of the rut of having only done homework assignments.

I've written my player and room classes (which were simple since I only need one class for each). I'm onto item classes (an item being anything in a room, such as a torch, a fire, a sign, a container, etc.). I'm unsure how to approach the item base class and derived classes. Here are the problems I'm having.

1. How do I tell whether an item is of a certain type in a non-shit way (there's a good chance I'm overthinking this)?

   - For example, I set up my print room info function so that in addition to whatever else it might do, it prints the name of every object in its inventory (i.e. inside of it) and I want it to print something special for a container object (the contents of its inventory for example).
   - The first part's easy because  every item has a name since the name attribute is part of the base item class. The container has an inventory though, which is an attribute unique to the container subclass.
   - It's my understanding that it's bad form to execute conditional logic based on the object's class type (because one's classes should be polymorphic) and I'm assuming (perhaps incorrectly) that it'd be weird and wrong to put a getHasInventory  accessor virtual function in the item base class (my assumption here is based on thinking it'd be crazy to put virtual functions for every derived class in the base class - I have about a dozen derived classes - a couple of which are derived classes of derived classes).
   - If that's all correct, what's an acceptable way to do this? One obvious thing is to add an itemType attribute to the base and then do conditional logic but this strikes me as wrong since it seems to just be a re-skinning of the checking class type solution. I'm unsure whether the above-mentioned assumptions are correct and what a good solution might be.
2. How should I structure my base class/classes and my derived classes?

   - I originally wrote them such that the item class was the base class and most other classes used single inheritance (except for a couple which had multi-level).
   - This seemed to present some awkwardness and repeating myself though. For example, I want a sign and a letter. A sign is a Readable Item > Untakeable Item > Item. A letter is a Readable Item > Takeable Item > Item. Because they all use single inheritance I need two different Readable Items, one that's takeable and one that's not (I know I could just make takeable and untakeable into attributes of the base in this instance and I did but this works as an example because I still have similar issues with other classes).
   - That seems icky to me so I took another stab at it and implemented them all using multiple inheritance & virtual inheritance. In my case that seems more flexible because I can compose classes of multiple classes and create a kind of component system for my classes.
   - Is one of these ways better than the other? Is there some third way that's better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible way to solve your problem is *polymorphism*. By using polymorphism you can (for example) have a single `describe` function which when invoked leads the item to describe itself to the player. You can do the same for `use`, and other common verbs.

---

Another way is to implement a more advanced input parser, which can recognize objects and pass on the verbs to some (polymorphic) function of the items for themselves to handle. For example each item could have a function returning a list of available verbs, together with a function returning a list of "names" for the items:

```
struct item
{
    // Return a list of verbs this item reacts to
    virtual std::vector<std::string> get_verbs() = 0;

    // Return a list of name aliases for this item
    virtual std::vector<std::string> get_names() = 0;

    // Describe this items to the player
    virtual void describe(player*) = 0;

    // Perform a specific verb, input is the full input line
    virtual void perform_verb(std::string verb, std::string input) = 0;
};

class base_torch : public item
{
public:
    std::vector<std::string> get_verbs() override
    {
        return { "light", "extinguish" };
    }

    // Return true if the torch is lit, false otherwise
    bool is_lit();

    void perform_verb(std::string verb, std::string) override
    {
        if (verb == "light")
        {
            // TODO: Make the torch "lit"
        }
        else
        {
            // TODO: Make the torch "extinguished"
        }
    }
};

class long_brown_torch : public base_torch
{
    std::vector<std::string> get_names() override
    {
        return { "long brown torch", "long torch", "brown torch", "torch" };
    }

    void describe(player* p) override
    {
        p->write("This is a long brown torch.");
        if (is_lit())
            p->write("The torch is burning.");
    }
};
```

Then if the player input e.g. `light brown torch` the parser looks through all available items (the ones in the players inventory followed by the items in the room), get each items name-list (call the items `get_names()` function) and compare it to the `brown torch`. If a match is found the parser calls the items `perform_verb` function passing the appropriate arguments (`item->perform_verb("light", "light brown torch")`).

You can even modify the parser (and the items) to handle adjectives separately, or even articles like `the`, or save the last used item so it can be referenced by using `it`.

Constructing the different rooms and items is tedious but still trivial once a good design has been made (and you really should spend some time creating requirement, analysis of the requirements, and creating a design). The really hard part is writing a decent parser.

---

Note that this is only two possible ways to handle items and verbs in such a game. There are many other ways, to many to list them all.

Comment: I appreciate the explanation and the detailed rundown. While I had exposure to the concept of polymorphism, I hadn't really seen it in action. This helped me understand how I'd use it for the item classes. I'd been so set in my previous way of thinking that I was looking at the problem with the idea of an outside print room info function that printed the item info and never thought to have the items describe themselves. It seems so obvious now. Thanks for helping me over that hurdle.

Comment: @slucas3816 Having an outside print room info function is not necessarily a bad approach, though it does depend on the case and which programming language you use.

Comment: @MelvinWM That's how I built it when I built this in Python and everything was a dictionary. All the items were just dicts and one of the key-value pairs was the item's type (just a string such as "container" that I gave it) so I could just check the type and only do valid things for the type, which totally worked but I'm sure would make any real programmer cringe. I had even less idea what I was doing when I built that than I do now (no programming classes) but I did manage to build a save/load system and a text parser that recognized verbs, nouns, prepositions, adjectives, and articles.

Comment: @slucas3816 Save/load system and a text parser, that's very nice, actually :). Without static type checking and good language support, I would believe that such an approach where you check the type can be a bit fragile reg. factors such as maintenance. But with those, that approach can actually be decent. I wonder whether an interesting learning experiment (maybe after you have built the C++ program) would be to port your Python program somewhat directly to a language such as Haskell, OCaml, F#, Scala, Rust, Typescript, but where you use tagged unions and pattern matching for the items.

Comment: @slucas3816 Of course, such languages might also include working with immutable data structures and collections, which may make the scope for porting it directly a bit too large, so if you think it could be fun and profitable for learning, it may make sense to wait until you have dabbled a little bit in functional programming.

Answer (score 1):

You are asking some excellent questions reg. how to design, structure and implement the program, as well as how to model the problem domain.

### OOP, 'methods' and approaches

The questions you ask indicate that you have learned about OOP (object-oriented programming). In a lot of introductory material on OOP, it is common to encourage modelling the problem domain directly through objects and subtyping and implementing functionality by adding methods to them. A classical example is modelling animals, with for instance an `Animal` type and two sub-types, `Duck` and `Cat`, and implementing functionality, for instance `walk`, `quack` and `mew`.

**Modelling the problem domain** directly with objects and subtyping can make sense, but it can also very much be overkill and bothersome compared to simply having a single or a few types with different fields describing what it is. In your case, I do believe a more complex modelling like you have with objects and subtypes or alternative approaches can make sense, since among other aspects you have functionality that varies depending on the type as well as somewhat complex data (like a container with an inventory). But it is something to keep in mind - there are different trade-offs, and sometimes, having a single type with multiple different fields for modelling the domain can make more sense overall.

**Implementing** the desired functionality through methods on a base class and subtypes likewise have different trade-offs, and it is not always a good approach for the given case. For one of your questions, you could do something like adding a `print` method or similar to the base type and each subtype, but this is not always that nice in practice (a simple example is that of a calculator application where simplifying the arithmetic expression the user enters (like `(3*x)*4/2`) might be bothersome to implement if one uses the approach of adding methods to the base class).

### Alternative approach - Tagged unions/sum types

There is a very nice fundamental abstraction known as ["tagged union"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tagged_union) (it is also known by the names "disjoint union" and "sum type"). The main idea about the tagged union is that you have a union of several different sets of instances, where which set the given instance belongs to matters. They are a superset of the feature in C++ known as `enum`. Regrettably, C++ does not currently support tagged unions, though there are research into it (for instance https://www.stroustrup.com/OpenPatternMatching.pdf , though this may be somewhat beyond you if you are a beginner programmer). As far as I can see, this fits very well with the example you have given here. An example in Scala would be (many other languages support tagged unions as well, such as Rust, Kotlin, Typescript, the ML-languages, Haskell, etc.):

```scala
sealed trait Item {
    val name: String
}

case class Book(val name: String) extends Item

case object Fire extends Item {
    val name = "Fire"
}

case class Container(val name: String, val inventory: List[Item]) extends Item
```

This describes your different kinds of items very well as far as I can see. Do note that Scala is a bit special in this regard, since it implements tagged unions through subtyping.

If you then wanted to implement some print functionality, you could then use ["pattern matching"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pattern_matching) to match which item you have and do functionality specific to that item. In languages that support pattern matching, this is convenient and non-fragile, since the pattern matching checks that you have covered each possible case (similar to `switch` in C++ over enums checking that you have covered each possible case). For instance in Scala:

```scala
def getDescription(item: Item): String = {
    item match {
        case Book(_) | Fire => item.name
        case Container(name, inventory) =>
            name + " contains: (" +
            inventory
                .map(getDescription(_))
                .mkString(", ") +
            ")"
    }
}

val description = getDescription(
    Container("Bag", List(Book("On Spelunking"), Fire))
)

println(description)
```

You can copy-paste the two snippets in here and try to run them: https://scalafiddle.io/ .

This kind of modelling works very well with what one might call "data types", where you have no or very little functionality in the classes themselves, and where the fields inside the classes basically are part of their interface ("interface" in the sense that you would like to change the implementations that uses the types if you ever add to, remove or change the fields of the types).

Conversely, I find a more conventional subtyping modelling and approach more convenient when the implementation inside of a class is not part of its interface, for instance if I have a base type that describes a collision system interface, and each of its subtypes have different performance characteristics, handy for different situations. Hiding and protecting the implementation since it is not part of the interface makes a lot of sense and fits very well with what one might call "mini-modules".

In C++ (and C), sometimes people do use tagged unions despite the lack of language support, in various ways. One way that I have seen being used in C is to make a C union (though do be careful reg. aspects such as memory and semantics) where an `enum` tag was used to differentiate between the different cases. This is error-prone, since you might easily end up accessing a field in one `enum` case that is not valid for that `enum` case.

You could also model your command input as a tagged union. That said, parsing can be somewhat challenging, and parsing libraries may be a bit involved if you are a beginner programmer; keeping the parsing somewhat simple might be a good idea.

### Side-notes

C++ is a special languages - I do not quite like it for cases where I do not care much about resource usage or runtime performance and the like for multiple different reasons, since it can be annoying and not that flexible to develop in. And it can be challenging to develop in, because you must always take great care to avoid [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). That said, if resource usage or runtime performance do matter, C++ can, depending on case, be a very good option. There are also a number of very useful and important insights in the C++ language and its community, such as RAII, ownership and lifetimes. My recommendation is that learning C++ is a good idea, but that you should also learn other languages, maybe for instance a statically-typed functional programming language. FP (functional programming) and languages supporting FP, has a number of advantages and drawbacks, but some of their advantages are very, very nice, especially reg. immutability as well as side-effects.

Of these languages, Rust may be the closest to C++ in certain regards, though I don't have experience with Rust and cannot therefore vouch for either the language or its community.

As a side-note, you may be interested in this Wikipedia-page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expression_problem .